# How to extract depth map of an image

Tags: android, image-processing

I want to create an app which captures a photo and then extracts the depth data of the image. I'm already done with the taking a photo part by using intent and sending it to the preexisting camera app. What I'm not getting is how do I extract the depth info.

I have looked at the exiftool and it can do what i need but i don't know how to use its functionality in the app.

Answer (score 0):

A photo (short for photography) by definition does not contain any depth information.
It represents a 2d lumincance distribution.

If you are interested in depth information you'll need multiple photos from different directions or distances or with different illumination. Or you actually measure the depth using techniques like time of flight, interferometry...

A simple photocamera won't give you any depth map.

Comment: i'm asking for those photos which have been snapped using dual cameras. I have read that they do store depth info as metadata and that is what i'm trying to access here.

Comment: @PenDragon start here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_DEPTH_OUTPUT

Answer (score 0):

You can take a photo using a compatible camera (with depth sensors). For example a Google Pixel 4 photo:

[image: Photo taken using a Google Pixel 4 camera]

Preview the photo in Photopea (to validate the depth maps were saved in the image):

[image: Depth Maps in Photopea]
https://www.photopea.com

Then you can use Exiftool to extract the depth maps to a separate file:

```
// Install exiftool on a Mac using HomeBrew
brew install exiftool

// To extract the first channel
exiftool -trailer -b photo.jpg > photo-depth.jpg

// Or to extract the second channel
exiftool photo.jpg -trailer -b | exiftool - -trailer -b > photo-depth.jpg
```

[image: Depth map trailer exported from Exiftool]

https://exiftool.org

You can then use a 3D photo viewer such as Depthy, to view as a 3D photo:

[image: 3D photo viewed in Depthy]

http://depthy.stamina.pl

Comment: in Photopea.com , press Window - More - 3D Depth Viewer, to preview your photo as 3D.